# Android phone turns off when WiFi is on

Tags: wi-fi, lock-screens, samsung, standby

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 that turns off when it sleeps or locks, but that only happens when it has internet access, not necessarily with WiFi on. So if I want to use the phone I have to disable the WiFi so that I can lock it, and if I want to use the internet I have to make sure it doesn't sleep, by touching the screen and stuff.

It does not turns off at random, only when WiFi is on and it sleeps. Sometimes it takes a bit of time for it to turn off even when the screen blacks out, and sometimes it instantly turns off when the screen goes black. Also, if I set WiFi to be disabled during sleep I can't receive email and stuff when the phone is locked, but it does not turn off.

So I prefer if there was another fix, I can't seem to find any problems as the phone worked fine before. I have not installed anything and I even did a factory reset from the backup menu in Settings.

Answer (score 1):

I must say, that's the weirdest thing relating to Android hardware that I've heard.  But anyway!

I would say that your next step would be to do a ROM re-flash using ODIN.  However, there are not any images available for the Ace 3.

So, I'm assuming WiFi doesn't work at all?  Being as soon as you turn it on, it turns your phone off?  Because that sounds almost like your WiFi modem has a some sort of "short" (that's the best word I could think of - I'm not necessarily saying an electrical short) in it, and it's causing your phone to die.

Sounds like you may be due for a new phone, unfortunately.

Comment: no, i can use WiFi but if the phone sleeps it turns off so i have to keep the screen on. basically if the phone sleep or lock while there is internet connection from WiFi then it turns off instead of locking

Comment: Ah, yes, you did say that.  My bad.  Very interesting situation.  Does the phone turn off, or does the screen not just turn back on?  Meaning, when it "turns off" after sleeping, are you sure it's actually 100% off, and not just the screen stuck black?

Comment: it turns off i have to keep the lock button pressed to turn it back on after it goes black